# Calling multiple functions in ObservableObject

Tags: swift, swiftui

I asked a question previously and I don't think I was clear on what I was trying to do. I've created an `ObservableObject` class that has to call two functions. I need call `load` for the new URL first then set that URL to `loadImage` but unsure how to call it properly to fetch a new image every button action. A user added a comment that the function doesn't know if the other completed, how would I fix this?

Currently it does fetch a new [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aMu6O.png) every button press but I had to add this but of code which doesn't seem correct in my content view.

```
func load() {
        info.load()
        info.loadImage(from: URL(string:info.cats.file)!)
    }
```

My `ObservableObject` class is below.

```
class CatInfo : ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var cats: RandomCats = RandomCats(file: "https://purr.objects-us-east-1.dream.io/i/kef4p.jpg")
    @Published var image: UIImage = UIImage(systemName:"exclamationmark")!
    
    var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = Set<AnyCancellable>()
    var loaded: Bool = false
    
    init(cats: RandomCats) {
        self.cats = cats
    }
    
    init() {
        load()
        loadImage(from: URL(string: self.cats.file)!)
    }

    func load() {
        URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: URL(string: "http://aws.random.cat/meow")!))
            .map(\.data)
            .decode(type: RandomCats.self, decoder: JSONDecoder())
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { data in
                self.cats = data
                print(self.cats.file)
            })
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }

    
    func loadImage(from url: URL) {
        URLSession.shared
            .dataTaskPublisher(for: URLRequest(url: url))
            .map(\.data)
            .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
            .sink(receiveCompletion: { completion in
                switch completion {
                case .finished:
                    break
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }, receiveValue: { data in
                if  let image = UIImage(data: data) {
                    self.image = image
                    self.loaded = true
                }
            })
            .store(in: &self.cancellables)
    }
}
```

In my content view, I created another load function calling both `func load()` and `func loadImage(from url: URL)` for my Button's action.

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var info: CatInfo
    public var defaultImage: UIImage = UIImage(systemName:"exclamationmark")!

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if info.loaded {
                Image(uiImage: (info.image))
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 300, height:500)
            } else {
                Image(systemName:"exclamationmark")
                    .resizable()
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                    .frame(width: 100, height:100)
                
            }
            Button(action: load, label: {
                Text("Randomize")
                    .font(.title2)
            })
        }
        .padding(.all)
    }

    func load() {
        info.load()
        info.loadImage(from: URL(string:info.cats.file)!)
    }
}
```

Comment: It's unclear to me what you're trying to accomplish. How are `load` function and `loadImage` function related to each other? Are you to load the image from an existing (i.e. already retrieved) URL and then update the URL with `load`? Or is it the opposite: `load` the new URL first, then use that URL to `loadImage`? As it's coded right now, the two functions are coded independent of each other, while being asynchronous. Which means that one function doesn't know if the other completed

Comment: I suggest that you rewrite the question with: what is the behavior you want to achieve, what do you observe (i.e. what's the bug), what are you getting back in the `load` call (we can only guess now), and also remove anything that's unrelated to the question (e.g. all the `#if os` stuff, styling, etc...)

Comment: I'm trying the opposite `load` the new URL first then set that URL to `loadImage`. That's exactly what I'm looking for, sorry for not wording it correctly. It will be updated.

Comment: I understand ur question , It's very easy with KingFisher. But we can do this in this way too.

Comment: @colecabral, looks like you found an approach, albeit you're mixing Combine and callbacks somewhat strangely. Generally speaking, Combine pipelines can be chained to sequence asynchronous calls, so you could create a pipeline that both loads data, then loads the image.

Comment: @NewDev So I removed the callbacks. Would calling `func loadImage(from url: URL)` in `func load()` be what you're talking about? I think another user commented on this. I can't find much resources on Combine pipelines.

Answer (score 0):

Since your Image depend on the random url you are getting from the internet, you have to call image loading function after you get image url.

1.remove `load()` in ContentView and call only `info.load()` inside button action instead.

2.call func `loadImage(from URL(string:info.cats.file)!)` after url receive value inside `load()`.

**Note:** you can do this using KingFisherSwiftUi very easily, with KingFisher you only have to give url to image view, you dont have to load image manually.

Comment: It would be nice to not use any third party tools. I'm essentially still learning the basics. I think I managed to solve my problem.

Comment: Did my answer help u?

Comment: Unfortunately it didn't help. Thank you though

Answer (score 0):

My understanding of your question is that you first need to get the image URL, then use that URL to actually load an image.

To achieve that with two asynchronous functions, you cannot call them synchronously one after the other. Rather, the second (dependent) function has to only be called when the first one completes, which can happen some unknown time later.

Typically, this use case is addressed either with callbacks (similar to what you did in your deleted answer), or by chaining Combine operators.

So, for example, if you had these functions:

```
func loadImageURL() -> AnyPublisher<URL, Error> {...}
func loadImage(for url: URL) -> AnyPublisher<UIImage, Error> {...}
```

then you could chain them to produce a final result:

```
let cancellable = loadImageURL()
   .flatMap { url in
      loadImage(for: url)
   }
   .catch { _ in Empty() } // ignore errors for simplicity
   .sink { image in
      self.image = image
   }
```

So, you could create a `func randomize() {..}` that does that, but it would keep generating new subscriptions. Alternatively, you could use a `PassthroughSubject` and set up a single subscription that keeps updating the `image` property:

```
class CatInfo: ObservableObject {
   @Published var image: UIImage? = nil
   private let randomizeSubject = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()
   private var cancellables: Set<AnyCancellable> = []

   init() {
      randomizeSubject
        .flatMap {
            loadImageURL().catch { _ in Empty() }
        }
        .flatMap { url in
            loadImage(for: url).catch { _ in Empty() }
        }
        .receive(on: DispatchQueue.main)
        .sink { [weak self] image in
            self?.image = image
        }
        .store(in: &cancellables)
   }

   func randomize() {
      randomizeSubject.send(())
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining it in detail, I’ll try that!  I managed to get it working without combine but I’ll see if I can incorporate this into what I have now.